# Show that $\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx\leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

Show that $$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}\,dx\leq \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Any Ideas, how to start ?!

Comment: Did you try use the mean value theorem?

Comment: Please read ["How to ask a good question"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), particularly the section on context.

Comment: ok anorton, I will read that. Although I had nothing else in mind while asking the Quest.

Comment: let me try that diegomath, by the way how do we tag ppl on MST

Comment: @Holycow Like this: note the symbol before the name. (There is auto-complete for usernames).

Comment: What techniques for approximating/estimating integrals do you know?

Answer (score 6):

Note that $x \mapsto { \sin x \over x}$ is decreasing on $[{\pi \over 4} , { \pi \over 2}]$, and
so ${\sin x \over x } \le { 2 \sqrt{2} \over \pi} $ on $[{\pi \over 4} , { \pi \over 2}]$.